gh has different output when captured with Python subprocess.run
Within Python, I am trying to capture the full stderr output produced from the shell command:
$ gh repo fork --remote
! knoepfel/larvecutils already exists
✓ Using existing remote origin

The python code looks like:
import subprocess

fork = subprocess.run(["gh", "repo", "fork", "--remote"], capture_output=True, text=True)
print(fork)

But what is printed to the screen is:
CompletedProcess(args=['gh', 'repo', 'fork', '--remote'], 
                 returncode=0, stdout='', 
                 stderr='knoepfel/larvecutils already exists\n')

In other words, it looks like the output after the newline has been truncated, and the leading ! is not included.  I'm wondering if this is because the ! and the ✓ are "special" (you don't see it above, but those characters are specially colored by gh).
Any ideas?

Note that programs often change their output depending on whether it's going to a TTY. Try running gh repo fork --remote > >(cat) 2>&1 at a shell -- if what I surmised above is accurate, it'll make the content identical to what Python gets.

You're right @CharlesDuffy--with your command the content is identical to what Python gets.

If we read the source code to the gh tool, this content is enclosed in a branch:
if connectedToTerminal {
    fmt.Fprintf(stderr, "%s Using existing remote %s\n", cs.SuccessIcon(), cs.Bold(remote.Name))
}

...using a variable previously set with:
connectedToTerminal := opts.IO.IsStdoutTTY() && opts.IO.IsStderrTTY() && opts.IO.IsStdinTTY()

When your content is being sent to a pipe, connectedToTerminal is false, so it's normal and expected that the log message above isn't printed.

Thanks @Charles Duffy, for the explanation.  Is there a way to make it think it's connected to a terminal?  It turns out the second line in the message is the one I want to capture.

Guess I'll see what I can do with import pty.

@KyleKnoepfel, ...site went down for a minute when I first tried to follow up earlier, but the quickest/easiest approach is to rely on a 3rd-party tool -- for example, you can wrap gh with unbuffer, shipped as part of expect; ['unbuffer', 'gh', ...] will make gh think it has a real TTY.

@KyleKnoepfel, ...also see How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal not a pipe (that said, note that gh looks at all three of stdin, stdout and stderr, so approaches that fake only stdout and stderr may not suffice).

You can try UTF-8 encoding as it will handle special characters correctly. The output might be getting trucated due to special characters
import subprocess

fork = subprocess.run(
    ["gh", "repo", "fork", "--remote"],
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
    encoding='utf-8'
)
print(fork.stderr)


Ignoring special characters requires an extra argument not being passed, and in no circumstance will Python just truncate the content as a whole (vs dropping individual characters) without throwing an exception. This is more likely on the gh tool's side than Python's side -- a program can call isatty() to determine whether its output is being presented direct to the user (in Python, that's os.isatty()).

...reading the source, gh does sometimes call os.isatty(), but here it's doing something even more interesting, trying to determine whether a terminal is "color-enabled" to toggle fancy output, with an environment variable further able to alter theme selection.
